# Could not find a method onclick(view) in the activity class

Tags: java, android, onclick

I have been getting the error "could not find a method onclick(view) in the activity class", for quite some time now and despite my best efforts I haven't made any sort of headway.

Here is my code:

LogCat:

```
02 15:44:48.972 14881-14881/edu.uwgb.ratemyanimal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: edu.uwgb.ratemyanimal, PID: 14881
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method switchImage(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'btnThumbsUp'
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(View.java:4757)
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4716)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

switchImage function:

```
public void switchImage()
{
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Function hit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Two onClickListeners that are commented out right now:

```
        // onclick
//        Button btnThumbsUp = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnThumbsUp);
//
//        btnThumbsUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                ImageView dogImage = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageDog);
////                dogImage.setImageResource(dogImages.get(index));
//                dogImage.setImageResource(dogImages.get(index));
//
//                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Function hit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//
//                index++;
//
//            }
//        });
//
//        Button btnThumbsDown = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnThumbDown);
//
//        btnThumbsDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//            }
//        });
```

XML for fragment:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/btnThumbsUp"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-118dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-751dp"
    android:text="Thumbs Up"
    android:onClick="switchImage"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideButtons" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/btnThumbDown"
    android:text="Thumbs Down"
    android:onClick="switchImage"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideButtons"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```

Things I have tried:

- Changing to button in the xml from `<Button/>` to `<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton`
- Calling the function through the XML with `        android:onClick="switchImage"
- Creating an actual `onClickListener` within the fragment's `onCreate` function

I have been trying to get this to work for quite some time. I have looked up many different things about this and nothing has worked. I have created various fragments inside of a bottom navigation bar and can't get my buttons to work for the life of me.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Here is the onCreateView method:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
//        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dog, container, false);

        Button btnThumbsUp = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnThumbsUp);

        btnThumbsUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ImageView dogImage = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageDog);
                dogImage.setImageResource(dogImages.get(index));

//                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Function hit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                index++;

            }
        });
```

Comment: I like the way you have tried the change to appcompat button was unnecessary. The calling from xml works only in an activity not fragment and lastly the solution should be done in the onCreateView of the fragment not in `onCreate` not activities. Check more info in the my answer below!

Answer (score 4):

The method you use with `android:onClick` attribute must take a single `View` argument. Change

```
public void switchImage()
```

to

```
public void switchImage(View view)
```

Also: the fact that the method has `getActivity()` in it hints that it is located in a fragment. Listener set via `android:onClick` attribute only searches your activity for the method, so it should be in the activity.

(Or alternatively: don't use `android:onClick` at all but the `findViewById()` and `setOnClickListener()` in fragment.)

Comment: Doing so did not seem to work: I still get the same error.

Comment: I'd say in a Fragment as OP calls `getActivity`. Would explain why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your method `switchImage(View view)` should be in an `Activity` for for this `android:onClick="switchImage"` to work and **NOT** in a `Fragment` .

And you said you tried to set `OnClicklistener` do in `onCreateView` of the `Fragment` **NOT** in `onCreate` (*Adviced for fragment!*) So I recommend you set onClickListener but not in `onCreate` method of a fragment but in `onCreateView`. This is because Fragments may have no context until attached to an activity.

Also after that your code improvement is that the application context is unnecessary to displaying a toast this way in this line:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Function hit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Remove the `getApplicationContext()` it is not necessary here just use `getActivity()`.

Comment: So what you're saying is that onClickListeners shouldn't be in fragments?

Comment: No it should be in a fragment but in onCreateView method not onCreate method @Matt

Comment: In fragment you can override onCreateView method not onCreate.@Matt